# I need to remove duplicates from an array from a specific code

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following code:

```
public function ajax()
{
    // Contains results
    $data = array();
    if( isset($this->request->get['keyword']) ) {
        // Parse all keywords to lowercase
        $keywords = strtolower( $this->request->get['keyword'] );
        // Perform search only if we have some keywords
        if( strlen($keywords) >= 3 ) {
            $parts = explode( ' ', $keywords );
            $add = '';
            // Generating search
            foreach( $parts as $part ) {
                $add .= ' AND (LOWER(pd.name) LIKE "%' . $this->db->escape($part) . '%"';
                $add .= ' OR LOWER(p.model) LIKE "%' . $this->db->escape($part) . '%")';
            }
            $add = substr( $add, 4 );
            $sql  = 'SELECT pd.product_id, pd.name, p.model FROM ' . DB_PREFIX . 'product_description AS pd ';
            $sql .= 'LEFT JOIN ' . DB_PREFIX . 'product AS p ON p.product_id = pd.product_id ';
            $sql .= 'LEFT JOIN ' . DB_PREFIX . 'product_to_store AS p2s ON p2s.product_id = pd.product_id ';
            $sql .= 'WHERE ' . $add . ' AND p.status = 1 ';
            $sql .= ' AND p2s.store_id =  ' . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id'); 
            $sql .= ' ORDER BY LOWER(pd.name) ASC, LOWER(p.model) ASC';
            $sql .= ' LIMIT 15';
            $res = $this->db->query( $sql );
            if( $res ) {
                $data = ( isset($res->rows) ) ? $res->rows : $res->row;

                // For the seo url stuff
                $basehref = 'product/product&keyword=' . $this->request->get['keyword'] . '&product_id=';
                foreach( $data as $key => $values ) {
                    $data[$key] = array(
                        'name' => htmlspecialchars_decode($values['name'] . ' (' . $values['model'] . ')', ENT_QUOTES),
                        'href' => $this->url->link($basehref . $values['product_id'])
                    );
                }
            }
        }
    }
    echo json_encode( $data );
}
```

So, the array generates a list of products, like for e.g.:

**Apple MacBook (Product Model 10)**

**Apple МакБук (Product Model 10)**

The problem is that those two products is actually one and the same product (same **product_id**) but in different languages, and both have the same URL.

So, what I want to check is, while making the **array**, the code to check if there is already a product with that **product_id** in the array, and if there is, not to add another one with the same **product_id**.

Practically, I don't want the **array** to generate two or more products with the same **product_id**.

**EDIT:** With Marc's code and ghbarratt suggestion work like a charm. A million thanks to you guys, and to all of you here.

**P.S.** How can I add ASC or DESC for **ORDER BY pd.language_id**:

```
$sql .= ' ORDER BY pd.language_id = ' . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id');

$sql .= ' , LOWER(pd.name) ASC, LOWER(p.model) ASC';
```

Comment: This code snippet does not make an array. Rather, it uses the `$data` array which is already defined. If you want help with making the array, we need to see the part of the code where it is defined.

Comment: Hey buddy, thanks for the fast answer. I edited my post, and now you can see the full code. Thanks again.

Comment: You can tell your database to not return duplicate products by product.id.

Comment: And how exactly would I do that? Sorry, have only basic knowledge of PHP and MySQL.

Comment: @Nikola Nastevski I think you would get more attention/answers to your P.S. if you posted it as a separate question. It sounds like marc's edited answer is good enough to be considered the selected answer of the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way should be to add another array to track already written ids and check with http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php:

```
$basehref = 'product/product&keyword=' . $this->request->get['keyword'] . '&product_id=';
$writtenIds = array();
foreach( $data as $key => $values ) {
    if(in_array($values['product_id'], $writtenIds)) 
    { 
        unset($data[$key]); 
        continue; 
    }
    $data[$key] = array(
        'name' => htmlspecialchars_decode($values['name'] . ' (' . $values['model'] . ')', ENT_QUOTES),
        'href' => $this->url->link($basehref . $values['product_id'])
    );
    $writtenIds[] = $values['product_id'];
}
```

Comment: Hey buddy, only yours code works, but it's a little bit buggy :) Now it shows:

Apple MacBook (Product Model 10)
Apple МакБук

i.e. only removes the (Product Model 10) from the second products. That thing in the brackets is product model.

Comment: In order to remove the duplicates you should replace `continue;` with 
`{ 
    unset($data[$key]); 
    continue; 
}`

Comment: ghbarratt is absolut right, I didn't know the data source when I posted my answer. I added ghbarratt's code.

Comment: Thank you guys a MILLION, you have no idea how brilliant this works now. THANK YOU. Can you also please just look at the end of my first post, where P.S. is? Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's another question, but just replace `ORDER BY` with `,` and it should work. Btw you don't have to begin the $sql.= in every row, you could use linebreaks inside the sql, that's no problem at all ;)

Comment: Yeap, it's fine now, and I will try with linebreaks :) But I saw that I will need to add ASC of DESC for the product_id order. Any help... again? :)

Comment: I don't know what you mean, please post your sql again. Of course you cannot use a `=` in an `ORDER BY` command. I also don't know what `(int)$this->config->get('config_language_id')` means?

Comment: I edited the P.S. of my first message. That (int)$this... is just to read the current active language, so don't pay attention to that :)

Comment: Just remove your config section, you cannot do that. Just do this: `ORDER BY pd.language_id ASC, LOWER(pd.name) ASC, LOWER(p.model) ASC`

Comment: No can do, huh? Hm... I can't remove the config section, because that's how I read which language is active. I will need to come up with some other solution then :) Ok buddy, thanks for you extremely GREAT help. Take care and see you around ;)

Comment: You mean to click Yes button on Was this post useful to you? If so, no problem ;)

Comment: Hey, me again :) Any chace to tweak the code for duplicates you wrote, to show only the last duplicate? So, if I have product_id=35, product_id=35, product_id=35, etc. only the last product to be shown, not the first like it's now? This way I will solve my problem for good :)

Comment: That's not in my code fragment, you have to change your `order by` maybe DESC by name, I don't know.

Comment: I was thinking about the array code you wrote. With your code, now it eliminates all the duplicates, and it shows only the first found of those duplicates. So, what I need is only the last found of those duplicates to be shown. Any chance? Or not possible? :)

Comment: Maybe if you add `ksort($data);` before the foreach loop but I'm not sure. Everything else would be getting ugly in the loop I think, sorry.

Comment: I think I finally solved it with array_reverse :) Dude, you have no idea how grateful I'm to you. Thank you again for everything.

Comment: And here we go again :) I returned to your original code, and it works just fine, but if there are two products with different product_id but same name, the products are not shown. Any ideas why this is like that? For e.g. if I have Apple MacBook with product_id=35 and Apple MacBook with product_id=49, none of those two products are shown. Any idea what in that code can block the same names to be shown?

Comment: I think you try to solve the problem at the wrong place - start again and think about your sql - you should modify it so it just returns the products in the language you want - maybe with a where condition `pd.language_id = ' . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id')`. It's getting too long here, if you don't get it to work, better post a new question.

Comment: I already put that and now it works with my initial code, without modifying anything else. But I want to search for all languages, so... :) Never mind, if I get it to work, I will post it here, otherwise I will use it as it is, with one langauge. Thanks again buddy, you've been of a great help. Take care and see you around.

Comment: But why didn't you do it? Ah, I give up.

Comment: You mean to click Yes button on Was this post useful to you? If so, no problem ;) – Nikola Nastevski Oct 18 at 12:31 
 
Yep that's what I mean – Marc Oct 18 at 13:07

I didn't even notice the YES arrow, I'm so sorry, I will do it now... Sorry again...

Comment: Yeah, you finally found the yes arrow! :)

Comment: Hey, I'm new around here, I need time to get used to it :) Take care buddy, and see you around ;)

Comment: Yeah and you did, no worries at all ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
$data = array();
foreach ($res->rows as $values) {
    $data[$values['product_id']] = array(
        'name' => ...,
        'href' => ...
    );
}
```

Guarantees unique product ids only.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is similar to Marc's except it will preserve the other names in an additional element on the data array for the product_id and it will make sure to remove the sub-arrays that have the same product_id as the first encountered one, which I believe is an important part of what you wanted to do.

```
$product_ids_added = array();

foreach( $data as $key => $values ) {

        $original_key = array_search($values['product_id'], $product_ids_added);

        if($original_key===false) {
                $data[$key] = array(
                        'name' => htmlspecialchars_decode($values['name'] . ' (' . $values['model'] . ')', ENT_QUOTES),
                        'href' => $this->url->link($basehref . $values['product_id'])
                );
                $product_ids_added[] = $values['product_id'];
        }
        else {
                unset($data[$key]);
                if(!isset($data[$original_key]['additional_names'])) $data[$original_key]['additional_names'] = array();
                $data[$original_key]['additional_names'][] = htmlspecialchars_decode($values['name'] . ' (' . $values['model'] . ')', ENT_QUOTES);
        }

}
```

Comment: @Nikola Nastevski I made this testing it along the way. I had to improvise some of the information. What is the error that you get when you attempt to use it? What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: Hey, sorry buddy, I didn't see your post. It doesn't show any error, it simply doesn't work.